# Check if value of column 1 exists anywhere in column 2, write result to column 3 (CSV document)

Tags: regex, bash, csv, comparison, sh

I am looking for a way to check if the value of column one (product name) exists anywhere in column two (product variant) and Write result (match/no match) to third column of a CSV document.

As this task is probably recurring, I would like to start working on a script for this.

The csv document is currently structured like this (third column contains no matches):

```
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"MATCH"
"100 DG";"black";""
"100 DG";"100 DG black";""
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";""
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";""
...
```

The result should look like this:

```
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"MATCH"
"100 DG";"black";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"yes"
...
```

So, I would like to write results to the third column:

- if contained write 'yes'
- if not contained write 'no'

I haven't done this kind of things in a while and appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you limited to using bash/sh? Can Python script be an option?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Could you post the code this question is about?

Comment: I tried other software solutions, but it turned out I am limited to near default Linux installs. Thus bash/sh was the option I chose.

Comment: @jonasjacek Okay, so Perl should also work, since it's included in almost every Linux default installation. See a beautiful one-liner below in my answer :)

Comment: I think that the Miller reply is the simplest and readable https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750730/757714

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "\"PRODUCT\";\"VARIANT\";\"MATCH\""
tail -n +2 $1 | while read CSVLINE ; do
    AMATCH=$(echo $CSVLINE | awk -F\; '{ print $1 }' | tr -d '"')
    BMATCH=$(echo $CSVLINE | awk -F\; '{ print $2 }')
    TESTGREP=$(echo $BMATCH | grep "$AMATCH")
    if [[ $TESTGREP ]] ; then
        echo "\""$AMATCH"\";"$BMATCH";\"yes\""
    else
        echo "\""$AMATCH"\";"$BMATCH";\"no\""
    fi
done
```

Example (`bash parse.sh file.csv`):

```
root:~# bash parse.sh file.csv
"100 DG";"black";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"yes"
root:~#
```

Comment: did you clobber the first line? I think you need to handle it specifically so that it is not processed, nor included in the search (for "PRODUCT").

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help and pushing me in the right direction. I just ordered a book on AWK.

Answer (score 1):

This is a task for awk

```
#! /bin/sh

FILE=$1

sed -e "s/\"//g" < $FILE | awk -F\; '{
        if (index($2,$1)) {
                result="yes"
        } else {
                result="no"
        }
        printf("\"%s\";\"%s\";\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, result)
}'
```

First get rid of all \" by using sed, rest is easy inside of awk.
-F sets the field separator to ";", which makes sense for CSV files.
Then use AWK's string function index.
AWK scripts embedded into a Shell script are very powerful.

Usage:

```
shell$ bash report.sh data
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"no"
"100 DG";"black";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"yes"
```

I like this variant, because 
a) it's good readable and maintainable code
b) it avoids having to start up a few other Unix jobs as everything is being handled inside this one AWK process (less cpu and i/o)

Answer (score 1):

with Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --csv --fs ";" put -S 'if ($VARIANT=~$PRODUCT) 
{$MATCH="yes"} 
    else 
{$MATCH="no"}' input_01.csv
```

or in one line

```
mlr --csv --fs ";" put -S 'if ($VARIANT=~$PRODUCT) {$MATCH="yes"} else {$MATCH="no"}' input_01.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a beautiful Perl one-liner for you:

`cat file.csv | perl -pe '/"(.*?)";"(.*?");""/; ($2 =~ /$1/) ? s/""/"yes"/ : s/""/"no"/'`

**Explanation**

`/"(.*?)";"(.*?");""/;` is a regex which gets the values of column 1 (at `$1`) and column two (at `$2`)

`($2 =~ /$1/)` is a condition, which means "column 1 is a substring of column 2"

Then we have a [ternary operator](https://www.perl.com/article/20/2013/4/16/The-conditional--ternary--operator/) which replaces `""` in the input string with `"yes"` if the condition is met, and with `"no"` otherwise.

**Example:**

```
user@server:~$ cat file.csv | perl -pe '/"(.*?)";"(.*?");""/; ($2 =~ /$1/) ? s/""/"yes"/ : s/""/"no"/'
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"MATCH"
"100 DG";"black";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.back -ape '$.>1 && s/"(.+?)";"(?:(?!\1)[^"])*(\1)?.*?";"\K/${2}?"yes":"no"/e' file
```

Where:

```
-i.back     # replace file inplace but keep a backup with extension `.back`
```

**Regex explanation:**

```
$.>1 &&     # if  line number greater than 1 (no change on first line)
s/          # substitute
  "(.+?)"   # capture the value of first column in group 1. 1 or more any character, not greedy
  ;"        # literally
  (?:       # start non capture group, tempered greedy token
    (?!\1)  # everything that is not the value contained in group 1 (i.e. the first column)
    [^"]    # 1 character that is not a double quote
  )*        # end group, may appear 0 or more time
  (\1)?     # group 2, same value as group 1, optional
  .*?       # 1 or more any character, not greedy
  ";"       # literally
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
/           # regex delim
  ${2}?     # does group 2 exist?
  "yes"     # it exits, change column 3 with "yes"
  :         # else
  "no"      # change column 3 with "yes"
/e          # end substitute, execute flag
```

**Output:**

```
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"MATCH"
"100 DG";"black";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F\; '{                               # set field separator
    v=$1                                    # duplicate $1 for ...
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",v)                      # ... removing quotes
    print $0 ";\"" ($2~v?"yes":"no") "\""   # print appending yes or no
}' file
```

Output:

```
"PRODUCT";"VARIANT";"MATCH";"no"
"100 DG";"black";"";"no"
"100 DG";"100 DG black";"";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG";"";"yes"
"100 DG";"silver 100 DG US edition";"";"yes"
```